# Validation for a 10 digit phone number

Tags: regex

I'm looking for a simple regex that will validate a 10 digit phone number. I'd like to make sure that the number is exactly 10 digits, no letters, hyphens or parens and that the first two digits do not start with 0 or 1. Can someone help out?

Comment: FYI - Good regex site: http://www.regular-expressions.info/

Comment: Thanks for the link. Bookmarked! It will help me for the future.

Comment: So this has nothing to do with the North American Numbering Plan, which certainly allows 0 and 1 as the second digit.  What area of the world are you looking at?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

/[2-9]{2}\d{8}/

Comment: I really have to learn some regex because I'm using it more now than ever before.

Comment: When one finds oneself saying to oneself that one should start to learn more about regexps, one should immediately take a step back and reconsider...

Comment: "qa 12345678901 asd" matches that regex as well

Comment: Regular Expressions seems ugly but there really beauty lies in their performance and capability. Each and every developer Must have knowledge about them!

Comment: This does not work for prefixes that have 1 as the second letter such as "415"

Answer (score 8):

```
^[2-9]{2}[0-9]{8}$
```

I consider [0-9] to be better to read than \d, especially considering the preceding [2-9]

The ^ and $ ensure that the input string consists ONLY of those 8 characters - otherwise it is not guaranteed that the input string is not larger - i.e. "12345678901" would match the regex w/o those two characters - although it is 11 chars and starts with a 1!

Comment: This does not work for prefixes that have 1 as the second letter such as "415"

Comment: @Mardok Yes. Exactly as the question asked.

Comment: Right you are I can't fault a bad question. Except it wont let me up vote you.

Answer (score 3):

As Randal pointed out, this question is not consistent with the way phone numbers are formatted in North America (even though the OP stated 'first two digits do not start with 0 or 1').  A better regex for North American phone numbers would be:

> ^[2-9]{1}[0-9]{9}$

For example, Washington DC's area code is (202). NYC has area code (212).  Northern New Jersey has (201).

But more accurately, the NANP has a lot of rules as it relates to what is allowed in area code and exchange (first six digits).  This regex should still cover most cases. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/North_American_Numbering_Plan

Comment: Where did he say it is for America?

Answer (score 1):

This regex script might help out. I essentially strips any "punctuation" characters, including a leading 1-, then validates it is 10 digits.

The extra part you probably don't need is the formatting to 000-000-0000

```
formatPhone = function() {
 var phone = this.value;
 phone = phone.replace(/^1(|-|\(|\)|\.| )*|-|\(|\)|\.| /g, '');
 if(phone.length === 10) {
   this.value = phone.slice(0,3) + '-' + phone.slice(3,6) + '-' + phone.slice(6,10);
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The Phone Numbers will be of 10 digits, and it will start from 7,8 and 9

[RegularExpression("^([07][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9] | 8[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9] | 9[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9])$", ErrorMessage = "Enter Valid Mobile Number")]

reference : **http://www.regular-expressions.info/numericranges.html**